AIX: BFF file can be extracted but not used for installation
I work in an ancient AIX 4.3.3 environment, please don't ask.
There is a BFF file from a legitimate AIX CDROM from which I must install a package.
I can interact just fine with the file with restore. Enumeration and extraction work as expected.
Unfortunately the same cannot said about inutoc or installp. The former doesn't generate an error message but doesn't give me a .toc file either. The latter errors out with:
# installp -l -d .
0503-003 installp:  The specified device /home/root/install/.
        is not a valid device or file.
#

This might be due to the lack of .toc file though.
I've poked at the processes with syscalls and trace, to no avail. AIX 4 doesn't have truss yet.
I have no reason to believe the file is corrupted.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Try this: rm .toc; installp -l -d .

There is no .toc file. See the post above. inutoc fails to create one.

You don't need to create .toc file, you only have to delete it, as it hinders installp. (Note: make sure to use ls -a to see hidden files.)

There is no .toc file in the directory.

Maybe /root/install is the point where your CD-ROM is mounted? If so, try to copy the file into another directory (such as ~/install_tmp and use installp) on that copy.
